# Phpmyadmin not allowing to create Mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a trigger on Phpmyadmin on shared hosting. But it's not allowing to create. giving message "You do not have enough privileges", Same code is working on my local database.

Please tell me how to create it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: same code is irrelevant if your account doesn't have the same privileges on both machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced same problem with my go-daddy shared hosting account.

Actually trigger requires super user privileges. And with shared hosting they (hosting side) will not provide super user privileges.

So finally You should have dedicated hosting. But this is not solution that I suggest to take dedicated hosting for just this single task. But yes, I can suggest you to tr to find a way to do task manually which you want to perform via trigger.

Also put a ticket on your hosting account with same problem. Let see what they reply.